# I'm Done button remain enabled even after the action is rolled back in First Posts Review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, review

From the [First Posts Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/) instructions:

> **I'm Done** is only available if you've done one of the following:
>
> - Vote up or down to rate the question's quality and usefulness
> - Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
> - Close questions that cannot or should not be answered here
>
> When in doubt, upvote the question and leave a comment to help the
>   user out, or click **Not Sure** if you are unsure and want to skip
>   this question.

That means that you have to do one of the above actions to click on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button. And if we click on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>, we get new post to review and our review count is increased by 1 (I think that's not important for anyone).

But I found (accidentally) a minor fault in *First Post Review*.
What I did is: I got a question, where I commented. And <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button got enabled. But deleted that comment as I found the comment was not useful. So I expected <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button to be disabled. But it was not disabled. It remained enabled. (That means it was enabled without reviewing.).

So I suggest to disable the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button again when comment is deleted.
(Same as when we vote the post then the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button is enable and when we rollback our vote(unvote) then <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button get disabled.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually plenty of ways to click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> without actually having "reviewed" a post. For example, you could upvote, click the post link and un-upvote it from there, then click "I'm Done". Or, close then re-open.

We may clean up some of these cases as time goes on, but for the most part, even a deleted comment, for example, indicates you gave the post at least *some* attention move on. If you want to make sure that the post stays in the queue for others to review, you can click <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> instead.