# Commenting then deleting it while reviewing still allows "I'm Done"

Tags: support, comments, review

As I was reviewing on SO I added a comment to an answer but then deleted it while still on the review page.

I was still given the option of "I'm Done". This obviously isn't intended and could be abused (get around audits?) if the end result is different than "No Action Needed" though it doesn't matter much if the result is the same.

Should it be fixed?

Comment: From where did you delete it? From review page or from original question page?

Comment: @hims056 Review page.

Comment: Confirmed this. Is it a bug? Perhaps retag as such?

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm this. But if we take it as review abuse, then such people (robo-reviewer who want to increase their review count) will use <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button instead of adding and deleting comment. Also suppose there is no button like <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>, still there are plenty of ways to abuse the review like

- [Adding comment on review page then click on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button then go to the post page and remove it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147196/187824).
- [Up/Down vote on review page then click on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button then go to the post page and undo the Up/Down vote.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147514/187824) etc...

And I know before the <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> came, <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> was getting disabled when removing comment while in review page. So I think this may be by design.

Comment: No Action Needed will fail audits. Yes those other methods you mentioned will work but I wanted everyone to be aware of another. Though there is no need to go to the post page to undo/remove anything, you can do that on the review page since the audit triggers when you first make the action not when you click I'm Done.

Comment: @AustinHenley - No Action Needed will fail only on Honeypot review. And that can also be passed.

Comment: @hims056 Aren't honeypots == audits?

Comment: @Asad - Yes. But why?

Comment: @Asad - Ohh got it why are you asking. Honeypot review means audits while reviewing.