# Broken UI on audit caused me to fail -- again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-audits

Just like my popular post, ["STOP! Look and Listen" audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404), I have once again been *fooled* by an audit having a **distracting** and **unusual** UI that does not happen for a non-audit review.

Just as before, since the post looked so different than a normal review, I thought my browser was messing up or my internet connection was lagging because part of the interface didn't appear.  The votes and user name were gone completely, as I highlight here (I don't have the original image because I didn't know what was going on!):

[image: broken audit]

I have pointed out numerous UI issues for audits:

- [Another indicator of a review audit: Question has no tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191110/169404) (recently posted; unfixed)
- [Review audits are too error-prone when reviewing on a mobile device](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165682/169404) (unfixed; probably won't be)
- [Commenting then deleting it while reviewing still allows “I'm Done”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/162079/169404) (fixed)
- ["STOP! Look and Listen" audit tricked me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156938/169404)

You say that audits are to make sure people are paying attention, but I am being **banned** for finding your **bugs**. I don't think I can pay much more attention than *that*.

## The broken UI is making me pay attention to *it*.

Not to the review.

**EDIT:** Also, if I remember correctly, the comments and `Add Comment` button were not displayed either.

Comment: Austin, how exactly was the review deceiving? It may be, but it's not clear from your post. What *was* the vote count (or was it missing?), and how did that throw you? Same with the user.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The vote count and username were both missing completely.

Comment: [This was a first-post review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2646136). What action did you take that triggered the failure?

Comment: I've been running across the missing user thing, but I've never encountered a missing vote count. But would those two things being present cause you to act any differently on the post? What action did you attempt to take that caused you to fail this audit? I would think by now you'd have learned that clicking random things is not a good option inside the review panel.

Comment: @animuson I would think by now these UI issues would be fixed :( There is an undo action for a reason.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I think I clicked one of the voting arrows to see if the UI would respond. I was jarred by the unexpected change in UI.

Comment: @animuson If I am allowed to undo actions in a non-audit review then I expect the **SAME** ability in **ALL** reviews. UI design 101.

Comment: Did you see the comment?

Comment: @Shog9 No, I don't believe any of the comments were shown.

Comment: What action did you perform then?

Comment: @Shog9 I think I clicked one of the vote arrows? Don't remember, I was just trying to see if anything was worked. I may have clicked No Action Needed or Skip with the intentions of going back and performing a action, if needed, after figuring out the UI problem. (I just clicked *something*)

Comment: @Shog9 **Bugs** should not be status-by-design. A difference in UI is a **bug**!!! It made me react to the interface, not to the post, which is **not** what audits are for.

Comment: Like I said, I can't reproduce the missing post score. Do you have any userscripts for SO/SE installed?

Comment: @Shog9 None. I will keep my eyes open for it again so that I can screenshot it.

Comment: With all these problems, I can't really imagine why anyone uses the review queues. I get just as much reviewing done by browsing the questions I'm interested in. I also make better decisions because I can evaluate the posts *in context*.

Comment: @CodyGray Very good point. I didn't even list the posts I have made reporting bugs in review queues that *aren't* about audits, such as not being able to see [previous edits while reviewing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191515/169404)

Comment: @CodyGray I can't speak for anybody else, but I use the review queues mainly because I'm hoping to be able to reproduce this error http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190687/this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit-edit-button-grayed-out before I get to 2,000 rep so I can add a screen shot with freehand red circles to the question, otherwise I'll probably never get an answer. ;)

Comment: "I use it in order to prove that it's broken." That is sad, @Adi. And since posting that comment, we've seen [more and more posts like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191929/why-did-flagging-this-audit-cause-me-to-fail-it).

Comment: @CodyGray Er...it was a joke. That's what the ";)" symbol usually means.  I apologize if my sense of humor depressed your spirits. The main reason I posted that comment was in the hope of drawing attention to the unanswered question, because I feel it would be gauche to make an edit that doesn't really add anything just to bump it to the top. And it worked! Very shortly after I posted that comment, I finally got an answer from a mod. :) :) And without the use of freehand red circles, too!! I did hope someone might get a chuckle out of it as well, but I appear to have failed in that respect. :(

Comment: BTW, I'm having a hard time figuring out what the connection is supposed to be between my comment and the post you linked to. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 9):

You saw a post that looked something like this:

[image: zero-score, anon author]

When in reality, the post looked more like this:

[image: high-score, high-rep author]

This is what is known as a "known-good audit" - it's intended to make sure you're able to recognize a decent post. Can you maybe see why the post score and author have to be faked in order for it to work in the **First Posts** queue?

If not, read this: [First Post suggests an answer from a "new user" who is 3+ years old with 1800 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164683/first-post-suggests-an-answer-from-a-new-user-who-is-3-years-old-with-1800-re)

Comment: The 0 wasn't there. The only thing it made me realize is the difference in UI (which should be considered as a bug).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce that.

Comment: While I have your attention, are [missing tags in reviews](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191110/169404) also status-by-design?

Comment: That's probably just an oversight; can't think of a reason off-hand to *not* have tags, unless it adds complexity to filtering.

Comment: Why would the "user" at the top be empty (sorry, don't think I've encountered one of these audits yet)?  Would that not be a dead giveaway that it's an audit of some sort?

Comment: Well, it would if you're paying attention. But not *all* audits look like this either. Should probably be attributed to "usernnnn" so as to look like a normal anon post.

Comment: I pay so much attention that it fails me :(

Comment: Still not sure why your reaction to a reasonable-looking answer with an odd-looking author would be "down-vote", @Austin...

Comment: My complaint is with late answers where an existing answer is shown as having been posted by User55555 (bogus?). I looked at questions page and thought someone had just copied and pasted the existing good up-voted answer.  I did too good of a job suppose?  Not a goof audit.  I'll just avoid doing reviews from now on.

Comment: @Shog9 Could you consider having an anonymous/unregistered "User838284" instead of a blank username space? Might prevent this looking weird.