# Why did flagging this audit cause me to fail it?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[Why {} == {} is false, but {} + {} == {} + {} is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774886/why-is-false-but-is-true) was part of [a First Posts audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2654142). I remember seeing [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the) and thought it was a possible duplicate. I went to flag as duplicate and I got the "STOP! Look and Listen." message.

Why was this the incorrect move?

Comment: Yet another borderline case. When something with that many votes shows up in the review queues, it's usually a good idea to go to the question and take a closer look.

Comment: This is why the audits need to be a little more patient. This was already predicted for the close-votes queue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It wasn't.

Duplicate scenarios, unfortunately, have the potential to break a lot of our "known good" audits.

I've been caught up by this too. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the audits a little more patient?

Comment: Yes - we could fake the flag and close UIs and wait until you chose an option before completing the audit. This is non-trivial though.

Comment: @Shog9 is "You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing." related to this?

Comment: @Nirk: Nope; I banned you manually. I realize you’re not robo-reviewing (and 7 days is arguably harsh), but *please* keep http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2661304, http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2661055, http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2661043, http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2661041, http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2661046, and really just most “first posts” things in mind. If you can do something, do it! “Contains recognizable words” is not the passing criterion.

Comment: @minitech I erred on the side of allowing things given the message that started this post (http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2654142).