# Audit question and duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, review-audits

I tried to close this audit question as a duplicate: [Using the 'new' modifier in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809604/using-the-new-modifier-in-c-sharp).

I thought the duplicate was: [C# Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842102/c-sharp-polymorphism).

Perhaps this question is not a good candidate for an audit. Please accept my apologies if I've made a mistake.

Comment: it's admitted bug in review audits design, and SE doesn't intend to fix it: "it kinda falls apart when you want to close a known-good question as a duplicate". See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770/165773) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191930/165773)

Answer (score 2):

Audits are selected automatically based on a number of factors (including age of the post, votes, views, open/close votes, etc).  The exact criteria varies depending on which review queue, but the general idea is the criteria attempt to find **obviously excellent** posts and **obviously poor quality** posts to ensure the reviewer is not paying attention.

It is not a perfect solution, and occasionally bad audit questions get selected.  Everyone fails an audit from time-to-time because of this.  One audit failure is nothing to worry about, but a history of audit failures will eventually trigger an automatic review ban, so you can't make a habit of failing audits.

Duplicates are a significant limitation as it doesn't handle that case well, simply because duplicates are a special case of closed questions that are not off-topic and may not be low quality.  Often they can be on-topic and good quality, so there is not a way to distinguish them automatically.  A known good audit may in fact be a duplicate of another question, but an attempt to close it as a duplicate would cause someone to fail because the system believes the question to be good and an attempt to close would trigger a failure.

If you review enough, you'll eventually get good a spotting audit questions, and know that an audit will never be a duplicate.  If you feel an audit is a duplicate, you can just visit the question outside of the review queue and vote to close it as a duplicate there

---

As for your proposed duplicate, I disagree that it was a duplicate.  Sure, there is a relation between the concepts, but if I am trying to figure out why something declared with the `new` modifier was behaving in a specific way, there is no way I would be able to get my answer by reading the question you thought was a duplicate.