# UX issue when flagging first posts

Tags: bug, review, new-users

Steps to replicate

1. Go to review first posts.
2. Flag the post.
3. Now, retract the flag (Use case: because my initial flag was a mistake and I needa change the flag to a different one).
4. I cannot Flag it anymore.
5. **But, I am able to click `I'm Done` button but it is not actually true.**

I think we need a fix for this so that the reviewed first posts are more accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm Done button remain enabled even after the action is rolled back in First Posts Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147196/im-done-button-remain-enabled-even-after-the-action-is-rolled-back-in-first-pos) - Different starting conditions (flagging) but same result. This duplicate was closed as status-by-design, no reason to expect that retracted flag isn't the same design.